# Google chat and Slack integration

Tags: slack, google-chat

My team is working mostly with google chat but we also work with different teams that work with slack
Is there a way to integarte google chat and slack so that massages in google chat will apear in slack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it natively but you can use a bot that when it sees a message (or a type of message) in one of the apps, then it sends a message to the other app.
You can either use an existing integration like zapier or develop your own app using each of their apis.